# How to protect against my Government?

Tags: surveillance

I have used the search but I wasn´t able to find anything called "government surveillance" or similar.

My Government is currently planning an new law against terrorism and child porn ;) Great isn´t it? I mean only Terrorists and Pedos can have anything against this law.

Well surprise, surprise it **can** also used for other things.

Among others this law allows:

- Spyware for the Police

  Can be installed per Bugs in the System or if this is not possible it is allowed to break into the house of an suspect. Completely without an court order although the home was an "special safe place". Of course is it only against Whatsapp like the Politicians say! Well, not exactly. The law says that every communication made by humans or the PC is meant.
- Blocking of Websites

  Can be done by the ISP without the action of anyone else. Of course it is only against Terror Material..... No? Oh! It´s against Pornography (which is not forbidden at all), violence adulation and Copyright infringement. I can already see the Terrorists tremble with fear. And there are no control mechanisms or sues against this blocks possible.
- More Video Surveillance and the connection of all state Organisations and willing private Video Cameras
- Either data retention or "Quick freeze" of the suspects data
- Surveillance of all cars on all High-ways
- Surveillance of suspects inside of cars (not specified how)
- Surveillance through IMSI-Catchers and Silent SMS
- Registration of Prepaid Cards (Full name, age, residence, etc)
- Identity card requirement to buy bus and train tickets
- Of course the secret service will keep the data secure and sound on their Systems (hahah).

  Alright, but there are also other people who shall get the data ;) **Private** people who are in "secure/security" positions shall get the data too ;P That are people in parent clubs, people you are living with, janitors and others in order to solve "neighbour conflicts".

btw, Who is an suspect? Everyone how has the possibility to communicate with an suspect.lol

Although this law is **clearly** against Terrorists it is enough to be possibly connected with an crime with one or more years of jail sentence to become an target. - it´s enough to forget to pay your aliments to be one of them.

I don´t knew somehow i do more and more mistrust the sate /it´s politicians the more they enforce such things....

How do I protect myself against these people? Let´s assume an normal guy who likes convenience like everyone else and is very worried where this goes (i.e.: air-gapped PC´s or not using a Smartphone are not convenient).  To tighten the Question, I am on Win10 mainly for Games and some Software + Android and online over WLAN.

Comment: Welcome, I'm voting to close this question because it currently appears far too broad. I understand that you're concerned about politics, but since this is a Q&A site, it's best to get straight to the point and focus on a single narrow (technical) question where we can help you with precise answers.

Comment: While there is no "government surveillance" tag, there is a [tag:privacy] tag. Check post associated to this tag, sort them by vote numbers to get the most popular first, this should already provide you a fair amount of information.

Comment: Start watching videos of DEFCON presentations. Over Tor, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

> Let´s assume an normal guy who likes convenience like everyone else and is very worried where this goes (i.e.: air-gapped PC´s or not using a Smartphone are not convenient)

Yeah, that's not going to work in today's world. It's that laziness that lets government agencies get away with things like this. Smartphones in particular are one of the biggest misnomers foisted on society, in that they're smart alright-- they do nothing but feed intelligence back to everybody but the user. We just keep scratching our heads, our only concern being why they become unusably slow every 18 months.

It sucks, but sometimes to gain security, you *do* have to give up something in return. You can have convenience or security, but not both.

Even so you'd have to go to some rather schizophrenic levels to be truly off the grid these days, but I'll address the rest of these topics as though I have unlimited time and resources to counter these measures:

**Spyware for the Police**

You need counter-intelligence. A good cellular-based home security system that alerts you when doors and windows are compromised. Hidden CCTV recording throughout. You'll know who's been in there tinkering with your stuff and how. Spooks are trained in how to look for and detect these things so you have to be comprehensive and sporadic. Dummy cameras that activate randomly and may or may not feed anywhere. Make them waste enough time chasing false leads that they miss a few real cameras.

Audit logs on the computer are likely to be useless and/or compromised. BIOS case-opened alerts are also useless. It sounds counter-intuitive but this is actually a physical security problem.

This honestly is one point I believe will ever only get used for terrorism cases, or child porn distributors/producers. It takes a lot of technical expertise that they're not going to want to waste on some kid torrenting copies of "Baby Driver."

**Blocking of Websites**

Use a VPN, or set up an EC2 instance in America and tunnel everything over ssh. Or Tor. The nature of the internet is such that when you encounter an obstacle, you route around it.

Most domestic pirates and internet users in developing nations figured this much out a long time ago. It's how they get Netflix in Nigeria.

**More Video Surveillance and the connection of all state Organisations and willing private Video Cameras**

This is nothing new. If you're in a public place these days, chances are someone is recording video of something around you on their phone and uploading it to YouTube. Facial recognition algorithms are surely scanning these videos. You're part of the social intelligence machine whether you like it or not.

Outside of your own home, everything is already watching you. If not traffic cameras, public CCTV or private CCTV, your phone is being tracked and so are its movements. They always know where you are and only need to issue a few subpoenas, then dial into localized CCTV feeds to see what you've been up to. Pretty soon even cars will be cellular-equipped and report their own geolocation metrics. We're already there with some models.

If you want to stay off the grid, first-- do not carry a phone. At all. Or cycle them out for disposable new ones every month or two, paying cash for them each time.

Second, you have to defeat facial recognition patterns. Wear a dust mask like they do in Asian countries, not a bandana like a hooligan. Cover your eyes if possible. Many FR algorithms depend on triangulating distance between eyes, lips and nostrils, or some combination thereof. Obscure these features as best you can (without coming across like the Unabomber) and you should be clear of most of what they're trying to do with these systems.

There was some hoopla a few years back where some ISIS militant on a beheading tape was identified through his full-facial hijab but I'm pretty sure they used his voice as a second data point and got him that way.

**Either data retention or "Quick freeze" of the suspects data**

Full-disk encryption. Use a strong password and don't ever leave your computer decrypted and unattended. The Alphabay guy just got busted because of this.

But there's currently a US child porn suspect rotting in prison on contempt charges because he refuses to unlock his drives for investigators to use as evidence in his CP trial. So they'll get you one way or another, even with countermeasures.

**Surveillance of all cars on all High-ways**

This has always been the case. LPRs aren't going anywhere, and you can't legally obscure your plate. Ride a bicycle.

In the country, some people with a habit of running from the law would make it a point to sling as much mud across the front and rear bumpers as they could in an effort to obscure the plates. You *will* get cited for this (and ruin your paint) but at least you can try to play innocent when it happens (as opposed to a license plate cover).

On motorcycles, the same thing, except they would bend the plate slightly into the wheelwell. The plate can be completely obscured (facing down) by popping a wheelie.

**Surveillance of suspects inside of cars (not specified how)**

FLIR, most likely. Not much you can do about this. Using IR techniques was controversial in the US some time ago (cops used it to bust a grow house without a warrant); I don't know where it stands now but this is likely what they're going to do to you people.

Lining your car with tinfoil won't do anything about the windows.

**Surveillance through IMSI-Catchers and Silent SMS**

Don't carry a phone, or use a burner. Nothing attributable to you. If they start requiring registration for burners, just don't carry a phone. Seriously, you don't actually *need* one. You can play games with "always make sure it's off" or "always take out the battery" (less possible with modern phones) but we've seen bulletins about certain overseas manufacturers who installed secondary batteries in laptops that keep the thing on even when you think it's off. For what purposes, and by who, take a wild guess. Your first answer will be correct.

If it's attributable to you, or you haven't audited the hardware personally, don't carry it.

**Registration of Prepaid Cards (Full name, age, residence, etc)**

Every time I've bought them in the US I just give fake information. Perhaps that's still an option if they don't verify. Aside from that, don't buy things online if you can avoid it (leaves a digital footprint anyway), or buy pre-registered cards second-hand.

**Identity card requirement to buy bus and train tickets**

Not much you can do about this. Ride a bicycle.

**Of course the secret service will keep the data secure and sound on their Systems (hahah).**

Feed them as much bad intel as you can. Their database gets hacked and all you've given them is fragments of activity across a handful of mobile devices, FR hasn't picked you up on any cameras, you don't drive so LPR isn't catching your plates moving across town, you pay cash for everything and buy (plausibly deniable) laundered gift cards off eBay using other laundered cards and have them sent to a dead drop. If you do it right, for all they know you're 42 different people. Just be careful who you talk to-- you may create a common denominator across your "identities."

Congratulations, you're a ghost!

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to cycle burner phones: Remember that "one phone disappearing, a different phone appearing" *is a pattern that law enforcement tools can specifically flag* as suspicious. Especially if there's traffic on the phones. So don't just bin the old one and start using the new; let them overlap for a while. And of course, in doing so, be careful that this doesn't give away too much information; for example, avoid keeping them in the same general area. For example, maybe there's a kid to a poor family on the block who'd love a free cell phone, even a simple feature phone?

Comment: Great points. I like the idea of giving it away to let someone else continue generating usage patterns. This will also scramble any geolocation attempts (like the felons who escape house arrest by transferring their tracking beacon to their cat).

Comment: While I do want to make it clear that I'm not encouraging illegal activities (and partaking in illegal activities tend to make government agencies *more* interested in you, not less), there is *likely* (IANAL, YMMV, etc.) no law that says you are obligated to make the work of local police (or other government agencies) tracking you down *easy*. Disinformation is a powerful tool; if you want to hide, always consider using it to your advantage by planting false leads here and there. It's in line with your final suggestion to feed bad intel, just extending it to other government agencies as well.

Answer (score 2):

However this question should be closed because it is too broad in my opinion, you are asking for complete privacy while giving up some of it by using a smartphone for example. Short answer to your question: You cannot 100% protect yourself against a government.

I also think it is not possible to protect yourself from a government if they target you specifically, so lets assume you want to protect yourself in general for being 'watched' by your government when they are not particularly interested in you.

Use a VPN at all times. This will make sure nobody will know your real IP address. Nobody? Well yes, the VPN provider knows it and your government can quite easily get the information so make sure your VPN provider is located in a different country at least.

Don't travel over highways if you are concerned about your privacy there, but use other roads. Will be significantly slower probably, but at least your government will not be able to use the camera's on highways for you.

You could use a laptop with a security operating system, such as [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) or [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). Although not 100% safe, it offers some more protection than Microsoft Windows in general. Oh by the way, consider hardware, including laptops, compromised anyway as the NSA documents that were leaked by Edward Snowden reveal that the NSA at least have exploits built right in the hardware itself and can monitor you through there. [You can read here how Stallman does it.](https://stallman.org/stallman-computing.html)

For your prepaid card, I would not know how they work in your country but over here in the Netherlands it is not required to register your details. Just make sure to pay cash, as money flow is an easy way to track people down.